# Initiate a jQuery plugin on multiple elements. Click triggered multiple times

Tags: jquery, triggers, click, toggle

I have written a very simple jQuery plugin to slice a `ul` or `ol` elements on the client side but I am witnessing very strange behaviour while initiating it on multiple elements. The plugin basically hides extra items in a list and just show a specified number of items. It appends a More/Less link to the list so a user can Toggle the items. Following is the code to the plugin.

```
/**
 * jQuery list slice v1.0
 *
 * Slices a list ('ul', 'ol') and shows a more/less link to either show more
 * or less 'li's respectively.
 *
 * @USAGE:
 *      For a list like the following:
 *
 *      <ul id="sample-list">
 *          <li>Item 1</li>
 *          <li>Item 2</li>
 *          <li>Item 3</li>
 *      </ul>
 *
 *      Initiate the sliceList as follows:
 *
 *      $('ul.sample-list').listSlice({
 *          default_items: 2, // Set Any other options here
 *      });
 */

(function($) {
    $.fn.listSlice = function(options) {
        // Merge or Override user defined options
        options = $.extend({}, $.fn.listSlice.options, options);

        var entity = $(this);

        /**
         * Slices the initiating list to show the number of default_items
         * and append a more link to the list.
         */
        function sliceList(){

            entity.find('li').addClass('listSliceItem');

            // Make sure we do not count items in ignore_list
            ignore_list = options.ignore_list.split(',');
            $.each(ignore_list, function() {
                var class_name = '.' + $.trim(this);
                var id_name = '#' + $.trim(this);

                var obj = entity.find(class_name);
                obj.removeClass('listSliceItem');
                if (!(obj.is('li'))) {
                    obj.closest('li').removeClass('listSliceItem');
                }

                var obj = entity.find(id_name);
                obj.removeClass('listSliceItem');
                if (!(obj.is('li'))) {
                    obj.closest('li').removeClass('listSliceItem');
                }
            });

            $.each(entity, function() {
                var current_entity = $(this);
                var should_apply = true;
                if((current_entity.find('li.listSliceItem').length) <= (
                        options.default_items)) {
                    should_apply = false;
                }

                // Make sure we apply more/less only to lists that have
                // enough 'li' elements.
                if(should_apply) {
                current_entity.find('li.listSliceItem' +
                            ':gt(' + (options.default_items - 1).toString() +
                            ')').hide();
                current_entity.append('<' + options.link_container +
                                ' class="' + options.link_container_class + '">' +
                                '<a href="#!" class="listSliceMore ' +
                                options.link_class + '">' + options.more_text + '</a>');
                }
            });

        }

        /**
         * uses the slideToggle method to toggle between showing more or less
         * list items in the initiated list.
         */
        function toggleMoreLess(btn){
            var dad = btn.parent().parent();
            dad.find('li.listSliceItem' +
                     ':gt(' + (options.default_items - 1).toString() +
                     ')').slideToggle(options.animation_time);
            btn.text(btn.text() == options.more_text ? options.less_text : options.more_text);
        }

        /**
         * Initiate the sliceList method and more link click method.
         */
        sliceList();
        $('a.listSliceMore').click( function() {
            toggleMoreLess($(this));
            return false; // Cancel Default Anchor Action.
                          // This prevents appending '#!' to the end of the url
        });
    }

    // Default options
    $.fn.listSlice.options = {

        // Default number of items to be displayed (Accepts Integer only).
        default_items: 5,

        // More Anchor link's label when hiding items (Accepts Strings only).
        more_text: 'More',

        // More Anchor link's label when showing all items (Accepts Strings only).
        less_text: 'Less',

        // Class names to be applied to the More link (Accepts Strings only).
        link_class: 'more link',

        // Class names to be applied to the More link's container (Accepts Strings only).
        link_container_class: 'more',

        // An element that wraps the more link. (Accepts Strings only)
        link_container: 'li',

        // Amount of time in miliseconds the show/hide animation should run.(Accepts Integer and Strings)
        animation_time: 500,

        // Ignore 'li' items to be counted as the part of list which have following classes
        // or id's. A comma separated list of classes or id's or both. (Accepts Strings Only)
        ignore_list: 'ignore, no-include, all',
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Now, Here is the scenario. Say I have the HTML format as follows:

```
<div id ="one">
    <ul class="item_list">
        <li> Sample Item </li>
        <li> Sample Item </li>
        <li> Sample Item </li>
        <li> Sample Item </li>
        <li> Sample Item </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id ="two">
    <ul class="item_list">
        <li> Sample Item </li>
        <li> Sample Item </li>
        <li> Sample Item </li>
        <li> Sample Item </li>
        <li> Sample Item </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id ="three">
    <ul class="item_list">
        <li> Sample Item </li>
        <li> Sample Item </li>
        <li> Sample Item </li>
        <li> Sample Item </li>
        <li> Sample Item </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id ="four">
    <ul class="item_list">
        <li> Sample Item </li>
        <li> Sample Item </li>
        <li> Sample Item </li>
        <li> Sample Item </li>
        <li> Sample Item </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and i initiate my plugin as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.item_list').listSlice();
</script>
```

It works absolutely fine. But say I want to set different options for the above four elements and I bind them separately as follows.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('div#one .item_list').listSlice({
        some_option: some_value,
    });
    $('div#two .item_list').listSlice({
        some_option: some_value,
    });
    $('div#three .item_list').listSlice({
        some_option: some_value,
    });
    $('div#four .item_list').listSlice({
        some_option: some_value,
    });
</script>
```

This is when it gets a little confusing. The behaviour I see here is:

1. If I click on the `more/less` link for the first list, Click gets triggered 4 times, so the animation slides up and down 4 times.
2. If I click on the more/less link for the second list, Click gets triggered 3 times.
3. If I click on the more/less link for the third list, Click gets triggered 2 times.
4. If I click on the more/less link for the fourth list, it works fine. (i.e Click being triggered only 1 time)

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TbKad/) showing the problem I am facing.

Does anybody has an idea what could be causing this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `preventDefault()` to your click handler on your More link. This will limit the action to just the `toggleMoreLess()` function:

```
    $('a.listSliceMore').click( function() {
        toggleMoreLess($(this));
        e.preventDefault();
        return false; // Cancel Default Anchor Action.
                      // This prevents appending '#!' to the end of the url
    });
```

Comment: Did try that but that doesn't help. Also, using `return false` does prevent the default action so I don't think that is the problem. The problem is that for some reason `listSlice()` method is being instantiated 4 times on the first list, 3 times on the second list and so on.

Comment: oops, Yeah, It does! should've been a caching issue last time i checked. Thanks.

Comment: Oh well, It actually worked because `e` here is not defined so it errors out. if you actually use `event.preventDefault()` it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiating the plugin more than one times, binds the `click` event to `a.listSliceMore` elements number of times the plugin was instantiated. I fixed it by making sure that i unbind the previous click event.

```
    $('a.listSliceMore').unbind('click').click( function() {
        toggleMoreLess($(this));
        return false; // Cancel Default Anchor Action.
                      // This prevents appending '#!' to the end of the url
    });
```